# keep rows where range is largest

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a file (fileA) which looks like this:

```
>ENST00000614578.1 gene=WASP12 CDS=1-526
>ENST00000581055.1 gene=PTP2 CDS=138-579
>ENST00000577541.1 gene=PTP2 CDS=1-81
>ENST00000423485.5 gene=PTP2 CDS=160-4752
>ENST00000367142.4 gene=PRPF40B CDS=304-1032
>ENST00000366955.7 gene=WASP12 CDS=169-9511
```

I would like to keep only the rows where the range of the CDS value is the largest. The range is given in the third column by the CDS value. For example the range of the first row is 525 (526-1) and the range of the second row is 441 (579-138)

Desired output:

```
>ENST00000423485.5 gene=PTP2 CDS=160-4752
>ENST00000367142.4 gene=PRPF40B CDS=304-1032
>ENST00000366955.7 gene=WASP12 CDS=169-9511
```

I tried by sorting

```
sort -nrk3,3  fileA
```

but I do not think is the way to go, any suggestion?
The filtering criteria is to take the maximum value of the range for the rows with same gene name

Comment: What do you mean by *"largest Desired output"*? Could you explain a little more?

Comment: I edited the explanation

Comment: In your command you are sorting, not filtering. In your desired output there's some filtering. What is the criteria to the filter? What constitutes the "largest"?

Comment: If you say "the largest", how do you define that? Your post may be interpreted as "the lines with the three largest ranges", but it could also mean "the lines where the range is as least 728". Please edit your post to clarify this, as the former is more difficult than the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come to this given the new information

```
awk -F'[ =-]' '{ print $0" "$6-$5 | "sort -k4nr" }' fileA | \
cut -d' ' -f1-3 | \
awk -F'[ =]' '!seen[$3]++'
```

Output:

```
>ENST00000366955.7 gene=WASP12 CDS=169-9511
>ENST00000423485.5 gene=PTP2 CDS=160-4752
>ENST00000367142.4 gene=PRPF40B CDS=304-1032
```

---

<sup>This surely can be done with one `awk` command, but I'm still learning to use it.</sup>

---

---

#### Previous answer before OP's editing:

Given a minimum value, let's say 700 (to match your sample output), you can try this:

```
awk -F'[=-]' '$4-$3 > 700' fileA
```

Output:

```
>ENST00000423485.5 gene=PTP2 CDS=160-4752
>ENST00000367142.4 gene=PRPF40B CDS=304-1032
>ENST00000366955.7 gene=WASP12 CDS=169-9511
```

---

`-F'[=-]'`: use `=` and `-` as column separators, wich leads to column 3 and 4:

```
1 526
138 579
1 81
160 4752
304 1032
169 9511
```

---

`$4-$3 > 700`: Select the rows where column 4 minus column 3 is larger than 700.

Comment: yes, this is working but I do not have only these rows, I have many values so I do not think it is a good idea to set a value > 700

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini 700 was just an example to match the data you posted. What is the criteria to filter the largest?. Have in mind that this was asked in the comments of your question.

Comment: Sure, the criteria is to take the maximum value of the range for the rows with same gene name

Comment: [edit] the question and add this information, so other users can answer as well. As soon as I can I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: For example, for row number 2, 3 and 4 which have same gene name (PTP2) the values of the range are 441 81 and 4592 so 4592 is taken

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini I've edited the answer, try it out.

Comment: thank you very much, the newly edited version worked well

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ranges are always presented on the positive strand and never in the opposite orientation, and assuming the columns in the original file are separated by single spaces,

```
$ awk -F '[ =-]' '{ k = $3; r = $6 - $5 } (m[k] == "" || m[k] < r) { d[k] = $0; m[k] = r } END { for (k in d) print d[k] }' file
>ENST00000366955.7 gene=WASP12 CDS=169-9511
>ENST00000367142.4 gene=PRPF40B CDS=304-1032
>ENST00000423485.5 gene=PTP2 CDS=160-4752
```

This treats the data as lines with fields delimited by spaces, `=` and `-`.  As such, the length of a range is found by taking the 6th field minus the 5th field. The maximum such range for any gene name is kept in the `m` (for "maximum") array, and the corresponding lines are kept in the `d` (for "data") array.

At the end, the collected data in `d` are outputted.

The `awk` code with somewhat nicer formatting:

```c
BEGIN { FS = "[ =-]" }

{
    k = $3
    r = $6 - $5
}

(m[k] == "" || m[k] < r) {
    d[k] = $0
    m[k] = r
}

END {
    for (k in d) print d[k]
}
```